# How to clone and append fields on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and what I'm trying to do here is I've 1 div like :

```
<div> <input /> <plusIcon></div>
```

Whenever someone clicks on plusIcon it should add one more div after that like :

```
<div> <input /> <plusIcon></div>
<div> <input /> <plusIcon></div>
```

In jQuery we can simply use `clone()` function and append but I don't know how to do it in react.

Please let me know if anybody know any way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of going about it is to keep a variable in your component state with the number of rows you have current, and every click on the `plusIcon` would increment this number. You could then use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create that many elements in the render method.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    rows: 1
  };

  addRow = () => {
    this.setState(({ rows }) => ({ rows: rows + 1 }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {Array.from({ length: this.state.rows }, (_, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <input />
            <button onClick={this.addRow}>+</button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```